# Google drive server to server - Seems 2b working, but no files uploaded

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am having difficulties with sever-2-server communication & Google drive. Here's what I've been trying:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import oauth2client
import googleapiclient.discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import urllib.request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("secret.json",scopes=SCOPES)
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
media = MediaFileUpload("fileupload.txt",mimetype='text/plain')
filen = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,media_body=media,fields='id').execute()
fileId = filen.get('id')
print('File ID: %s' % fileId)
```

Everything seems to be working just fine. No errors and I even get a FileID printed, e.g.:

```
File ID: 1kIDop9cX5CvL5jxxxxxxxxxxxxyP
```

But looking into the Google drive folder, I cannot find the file. Not even in the "recent files" tab. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are not impersonating a user so the file is being uploaded to the service account drive. Please take a look at this answer and that should take care of the issue... https://stackoverflow.com/a/42449497/5983596

Comment: Are you searching in your own Google Drive account and not the service account's Google Drive ?

Comment: @noogui Yes, I've been searching ing my Google Drive account. I had no idea there is such a thing like a service account's own Drive. Now I know what's going wrong, thank you!

Comment: Did that resolve your problem?